# Conditional query with a parameter stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I'm learning SQL so I don't know yet all the subtlety of the language,

I wrote the following stored procedure (simplified here):

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectAllIssues]
    @Status nvarchar(1) = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @Status = 1 OR @Status = 2
    BEGIN
        SELECT IssueStatuses.Id AS 'StatusId'
        FROM Issues 
        INNER JOIN IssueStatuses ON Issues.IssueStatusId = IssueStatuses.Id
        WHERE Issues.IssueStatusId = @Status
        ORDER BY Created
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT IssueStatuses.Id AS 'StatusId'
        FROM Issues 
        INNER JOIN IssueStatuses ON Issues.IssueStatusId = IssueStatuses.Id
        ORDER BY Created
    END 
END
```

But it doesn't look like a natural way to do that and there is a lot of repeated code.

I want to avoid something like

```sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStrComplet
```

But if it's the only way.

I don't know the correct tag but `sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB` return

Version : 13.1.4001.0

and I use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Comment: `WHERE Issues.IssueStatusId = @Status OR @Status NOT IN (1, 2)`

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and stored procedures are vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

```
select s.Id as StatusId
from issues i
inner join IssueStatuses s on i.IssueStatusId = s.Id
where (i.IssueStatusId = @Status and @status in (1, 2)) or @status not in (1, 2)
Order By created
```

The `where` clause can be simplified:

```
where i.IssueStatusId = @Status or @status not in (1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you! This code works but I don't understand why. I will take a look at _not in_ def and I will validate your answer as soon as I understand it.